# docker service virtual IP is unreachable

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm of a single node. I've deployed a image registry as a service:

```
  docker service create \
  --name image-registry \
  --hostname image-registry.localdomain.local \
  --secret image-registry.crt \
  --secret image-registry.key \
  --constraint 'node.labels.registry==true' \
  --mount type=bind,src=/var/image-registry/,dst=/var/lib/registry \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/run/secrets/image-registry.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/run/secrets/image-registry.key \
  --publish published=443,target=443 \
  --replicas 1 \
  registry:2
```

The service seems healthy

```
$ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS
ywt51zvik09s        image-registry      replicated          1/1                 registry:2          *:443->443/tcp
```

I inspect the service to find the virtual IP

```
$ docker service inspect image-registry
[
    {
        "ID": "ywt51zvik09szz2jl9xgxbj8i",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 54378
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2017-11-29T02:01:04.063664587Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2017-11-29T02:01:04.065183181Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "image-registry",
            "Labels": {},
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "registry:2@sha256:d837de65fd9bdb81d74055f1dc9cc9154ad5d8d5328f42f57f273000c402c76d",
                    "Hostname": "image-registry.localdomain.local",
                    "Env": [
                        "REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443",
                        "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/run/secrets/image-registry.crt",
                        "REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/run/secrets/image-registry.key"
                    ],
                    "Mounts": [
                        {
                            "Type": "bind",
                            "Source": "/var/image-registry/",
                            "Target": "/var/lib/registry"
                        }
                    ],
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Secrets": [
                        {
                            "File": {
                                "Name": "image-registry.crt",
                                "UID": "0",
                                "GID": "0",
                                "Mode": 292
                            },
                            "SecretID": "t88ee92s2sax4ewihbbrmwwyw",
                            "SecretName": "image-registry.crt"
                        },
                        {
                            "File": {
                                "Name": "image-registry.key",
                                "UID": "0",
                                "GID": "0",
                                "Mode": 292
                            },
                            "SecretID": "srsaybf31lqpl942rfmlndm4h",
                            "SecretName": "image-registry.key"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Resources": {
                    "Limits": {},
                    "Reservations": {}
                },
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Constraints": [
                        "node.labels.registry==true"
                    ],
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 443,
                        "PublishedPort": 443,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 443,
                        "PublishedPort": 443,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 443,
                    "PublishedPort": 443,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "d5pvc254jq5e1n0e16v8ecp1j",
                    "Addr": "10.255.0.3/16"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

But when I try to ping from the host the virtual IP I get:

```
ping 10.255.0.3
PING 10.255.0.3 (10.255.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 65.12.13.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 65.12.13.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 65.12.13.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 65.12.13.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
```

When I do `ifconfig` I don't see any of these networks:

```
$ ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:47:e7:22:43  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

docker_gwbridge Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:b9:0c:1c  
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:feb9:c1c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:91 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:9348 (9.3 KB)

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:1b:0d:7e:ad:b2  
          inet addr:192.168.1.148  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fdfb:4eb5:df66:0:e0c0:4e3:83d2:63de/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::66e0:994a:2ae7:8180/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fdfb:4eb5:df66:0:986b:be9b:687a:48d0/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:993615 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:617970 errors:6 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1333226168 (1.3 GB)  TX bytes:55076679 (55.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:165431 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:165431 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:25958351 (25.9 MB)  TX bytes:25958351 (25.9 MB)

veth4bd29fc Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c2:ef:1c:ba:6e:f3  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c0ef:1cff:feba:6ef3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:82 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:8059 (8.0 KB)

vethb2889ca Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c2:9d:1a:df:8f:a8  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c09d:1aff:fedf:8fa8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:150 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:15411 (15.4 KB)
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: ip mentioned above is virtual-box vm address?

Comment: I've updated the question with the output of `ifconfig`

Answer (score -1):

You're inspecting the service, rather than the container. Beginner mistake :-) Docker has a lot of "inspect" commands that can be used in various areas.

You want to inspect the container, which is either:

- `docker inspect [container_id]` or
- `docker container inspect [container_id]`

Either works; however the new way is the second option; as the number of subcommands has grown - Docker began splitting them up.

**Note** You must use the container ID - not the service ID! Find this via a `docker ps`.

As an example:

```
➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
28409910f4b2        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   47 hours ago        Up 47 hours         80/tcp              lucid_feynman

➜  ~ docker inspect --format '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' 28409910f4b2
172.17.0.2
```

Comment: but wait, I was under the impression that 'virtual IP' is the ingress ip interface from outside the swarm to services running in it. If all docker hosts are proxying the same published ports, that means that you cannot advertise, say, port 80 twice in the swarm?

I was planning to rely on the 'virtual IP' info to build DNS information to route service requests....what should I use instead?

Comment: That address you referenced before is not an IP; it's a subnet. An IP would be `/32` where as `/16` encompasses the network of `10.255.0.0 - 10.255.256.256`.

You'll be able to advertise port 80 multiple times in a swarm, if it's multiple instances - but not if there's only a single instance.

Comment: "_An IP would be /32 where as /16 encompasses the network of 10.255.0.0 - 10.255.256.256._" An IP (Internet Protocol) would be either IPv4 (IP version 4) or IPv6 (IP version 6). An IPv4 _address_ would be `/32` and an IPv6 _address_ would be `/128`. The IPv4 address range of `/16` encompasses `x.x.0.0` to `x.x.255.255`. An IPv4 octet of `256` is invalid.